# Scala - Overloading method in implicit class

Tags: scala, overloading, implicit, quill

I currently have an issue where I am trying to overload a method contained within quill using an implicit class, normally this is possible with the simple case, i.e. if you have something like

```
class Test {
  def rawr(string: String): String = string
}
```

You can easily overload this definition of `rawr` using a different type like so

```
implicit final class RawrExt(val t: Test) {
  def rawr(int: Int): Int = int
}
```

And this compiles as expected, i.e.

```
val t = new Test
t.rawr(5)
```

Even if `Test` has more complex type parameters, this still works, i.e.

```
class Test[T <: Number] {
  def rawr(string: String): String = string
}

implicit final class RawrExt[N <: Number](val t: Test[N]) {
  def rawr(int: Int): Int = int
}

val t = new Test[BigDecimal]
t.rawr(5)
```

Where I am getting a problem is when I am trying to implement the exact same overloading for the quill-monix-jdbc's transaction. When using monix-quill-jdbc, you have a transaction method that has the following signature

```
def transaction[A](f: Task[A]): Task[A]
```

The issue is that we are using `TaskResult` in our application logic which is Monad Transformer of `Either` and `Task` using cats, i.e.

```
type TaskResult[T] = EitherT[Task, GeneralError, T]
```

What I am trying to do is to provide an override for `transaction` which takes `TaskResult` rather than `Task`, defining this in an `implicit class` is quite straight forward

```
object TaskResultSupport {
  implicit final class TaskResultCtxSupport[Dialect <: SqlIdiom, Naming <: NamingStrategy](
      val value: MonixJdbcContext[Dialect, Naming]) {

    def transaction[A](f: TaskResult[A]): TaskResult[A] =
      EitherT(value.transaction(f.value))
  }
}
```

And then when we try to use it we get a compilation error, it can't seem to pick up the `implicit class`.

```
val ctx: PostgresMonixJdbcContext[SnakeCase] =
  new PostgresMonixJdbcContext(SnakeCase, "database")

val taskResult: TaskResult[Unit] = TaskResult(())

ctx.transaction(taskResult) // This doesn't compile
```

I tried all various permutations of defining the implicit class, i.e. as an example

```
implicit final class TaskResultCtxSupport(val value: MonixJdbcContext[_, _]) extends AnyVal
```

And none seem to work. Here is the compilation error

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Playground.this.Implicits.TaskResult[Unit]
    (which expands to)  cats.data.EitherT[monix.eval.Task,Playground.this.GeneralError,Unit]
 required: monix.eval.Task[?]
```

A scastie demonstrating the problem can be found here https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pqAn8fUPTbmBqToCVIXDXA. Thanks to Martjin Hoekstra, there is a further minimized example here https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4YrhP0HSRzu7F9numrqAGQ. Scala contributors thread can be found here https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/scala-compiler-unable-to-overload-methods-with-type-parameters/3761

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Comment: Its in the scastie, but I will edit the post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a bug with the current Scala compiler, a solution is slated for 2.13. See https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7396 for more details.